# Is there any way to overload the += operator in C#

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload an `+=` operator in my c# code, basically only to add a `keyValuePair` struct to a `Hashtable` (in this case, its a class inheriting from the `Hashtable` Class)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var x = new HashClass();
        x.Add("one", "one");
        x.Add("two", "two");

        var y = x + new KeyValuePair<string, string>("three", "three");
        y += new KeyValuePair<string, string>("four", "four");

        foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry z in y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(z.Key + " " + z.Value);
        }
    }
}

public class HashClass : System.Collections.Hashtable
{
    public static System.Collections.Hashtable operator +(HashClass itema, KeyValuePair<string, string> itemb)
    {
        itema.Add(itemb.Key, itemb.Value);
        return itema;
    }

    public static System.Collections.Hashtable operator +=(HashClass itema, KeyValuePair<string, string> itemb)
    {
        itema.Add(itemb.Key, itemb.Value);
        return itema;
    }

    public static implicit operator HashClass(KeyValuePair<string, string> item)
    {
        var x = new HashClass();
        x.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        return x;
    }
}
```

The following errors pop up:

1. Overloadable binary operator expected (**I thought += was a valid operator. Are there special rules attached?**
2. Operator "+=" Cannot be applied to operands of type 'Hashtable' and 'KeyValuePair'- *This kind of makes sense. My variably `y` has implicitly been converted now to a Hashtable. As a theory, I thought that this part will fail because `y` is not a HashClass*

What else can I try to overload the += operator? Is this even possible?

Comment: _AFAIK_, you can't overload `+=` but you _can_ overload `+` operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to overload the `+` operator because `+=` is just a syntactic sugar, e.g:

```
x += 1
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x + 1;
```

Comment: This doesn't really help, unless the OP is okay with having `hashtable + value` modify `hashtable`, or creating a brand new hashtable each time.

Comment: @hvd Then this simply means that it's not a good idea to overload operators for a hashtable.

Comment: I clicked. Even if the += is syntactic sugar for the += override, it still won't help the fact that `Hashtable` cannot implicitly cast into `Hashclass` in my case. So much for the lay approach :)

Comment: Changing the type which the operator +(...) returns to Hashclass worked for me though. Thanks. this is the answer

Answer (score 1):

No, You can't overload `+=` operator. But you can overload `+` operator.

> Assignment operators cannot be overloaded, but +=, for example, is evaluated using +, which can be overloaded.

[From Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can´t overload += operator.
you can modify your code like this :

```
 var y = x + new KeyValuePair<string, string>("three", "three");
        y = y + new KeyValuePair<string, string>("four", "four");
```

and it will work as you want.